Fetch the partition name from ALL_TAB_PARTITIONS table using the partition value in Oracle
I am newbie to Oracle and there is a list partitioned table based on a date column in the database. I am trying to create a table with one static partition and using automatic keyword to create next partitions automatically using the column name. Below is the syntax of my table DDL
CREATE TABLE INSURANCE_PAYMENT 
   (CLAIM_NUMBER VARCHAR2(26 CHAR), 
    CHECK_NUMBER VARCHAR2(20 CHAR), 
    CHECK_DATE TIMESTAMP, 
    PAY_TYPE VARCHAR2(10 CHAR), 
    CHECK_AMOUNT NUMBER(38,2) 
    D_CYCLE_DATE_R DATE
   )
   PARTITION BY LIST (D_CYCLE_DATE_R) AUTOMATIC (
   PARTITION P1 VALUES (TO_DATE('2024-05-29', 'YYYY-MM-DD'))); 

If query the ALL_TAB_PARTITIONS table to check the partition columns of the table it is giving below result

P1 is static partition and SYS_P6533 is a dynamic partition and I am trying to fetch partition name using partition value for example the P1 partition created for date '2024-05-29' using below query
SELECT PARTITION_NAME FROM ALL_TAB_PARTITIONS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'INSURANCE_PAYMENT' AND HIGH_VALUE = 
TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('2024-05-29', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS'))

I am getting below error
ORA-00997: illegal use of LONG datatype
00997. 00000 -  "illegal use of LONG datatype"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 11 Column: 51

I am confused it says HIGH_VALUE is long type, but value inserted in the table for it looks weird "TO_DATE(' 2024-05-29 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN')". I want the Partition column name to truncate the data in the partition as per the business requirements.
Please help me how can i get the partition name based on the partition value or is there any way to get the partition name. Please let me know if you need any more information.

long is Oracle is a deprecated (sort of, except for internal Oracle use still) text data type, so that value is just the text for the condition that is used to identify the top of that partition; it isn't a numeric type as you might expect from other languages. Anyway... why do you need to know the partition name? What do you plan to do with it?

@AlexPoole i want to truncate the data in the partition based on some business logic.

You can either use the new partition for syntax or a PL/SQL block that fetches the long into a local varchar2 variable, which you can then evaluate and test.

It's possible to get the partition name, but it's not simple; here's one way you could adapt.

I want the Partition column name to truncate the data in the partition

You don't need to know its name, you can use partition for (<values>).
If you start off with say three partitions, one manual and two automatic, with data only in the automatic ones:
select partition_name, high_value from user_tab_partitions




PARTITION_NAME
HIGH_VALUE




P1
TO_DATE(' 2024-05-29 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN')


SYS_P23798
TO_DATE(' 2024-06-26 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss', 'nls_calendar=gregorian')


SYS_P23799
TO_DATE(' 2024-07-24 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss', 'nls_calendar=gregorian')



select d_cycle_date_r
from insurance_payment




D_CYCLE_DATE_R




26-JUN-24


24-JUL-24



Then you can query based on the partition value:
select d_cycle_date_r
from insurance_payment partition for (date '2024-06-26')




D_CYCLE_DATE_R




26-JUN-24



select d_cycle_date_r
from insurance_payment partition for (date '2024-07-24')




D_CYCLE_DATE_R




24-JUL-24



and you can truncate a partition in the same way:
alter table insurance_payment
truncate partition for (date '2024-06-26')

select d_cycle_date_r
from insurance_payment




D_CYCLE_DATE_R




24-JUL-24



fiddle

You can use the same mechanism to drop partitions as well:
alter table insurance_payment
drop partition for (date '2024-06-26')

alter table insurance_payment
drop partition for (date '2024-05-29')

select d_cycle_date_r
from insurance_payment




D_CYCLE_DATE_R




24-JUL-24



select partition_name, high_value from user_tab_partitions




PARTITION_NAME
HIGH_VALUE




SYS_P23754
TO_DATE(' 2024-07-24 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss', 'nls_calendar=gregorian')



fiddle

Um, yes,.. I was only thinking about the truncate statement, not alter table truncate partition. D'oh...

You can try this one:
DECLARE
    d DATE;
BEGIN

    FOR aPart IN (SELECT * FROM ALL_TAB_PARTITIONS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'INSURANCE_PAYMENT') LOOP
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN :ret := '||aPart.HIGH_VALUE||'; END;' USING OUT d;
        IF d = TO_DATE('2024-05-29', 'YYYY-MM-DD') THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(aPart.PARTITION_NAME );
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE INSURANCE_PAYMENT TRUNCATE PARTITION ' || aPart.PARTITION_NAME; 
        END IF;
    END LOOP;

END;

